# Where "use in layered navigation" attribute property is stored in the database?

Tags: database, attributes, navigation

I am looking for where (what table) in the `Magento 1.9.0.3` database this attributes property "`use in layered navigation`" is stored. I actually new it but now it takes a lot of time to remember. Maybe someone can help out right away? Thanks.

Searched in `eav_attribute`, `eav_attribute_option`. No luck yet :)

I need to select all the attributes ids with "`use in layered navigation`" enabled
programmatically.

[image]

Comment: check my answer it will help you.

Answer (score 6):

That value stored in `catalog_eav_attribute` table.

[image]

If you simply want to get all attributes that are set as filterable via the admin section then you need to filter on the table `catalog_eav_attribute` where the column `is_filterable` is true:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection $attributeCollection */
$attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$attributeCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_filterable', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's catalog_eav_attribute.is_filterable: 
(used information_schema.columns to find out)

This select works for me:

```
select 
  a.attribute_id
, a.attribute_code
, ca.is_filterable 
from
  catalog_eav_attribute ca
inner JOIN  
  eav_attribute a
on  
  a.attribute_id = ca.attribute_id
where
  is_filterable in 
  ( 
    1 -- filterable(with results)
  , 2 -- filterable(with no results)
  )
```